# D3.js axes not honoring SVG size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I can't seem to be able to place my `xaxis` and `yaxis` to the bottom and left of the SVG.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
svg {width:350px; height:280px;border-style:solid;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<svg />

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 80]).range([0, 200]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 80]).range([200, 0]);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').ticks(4);
var yaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').ticks(4);

var svg = d3.select('svg');
//svg.attr('width', 300).attr('height', 300);
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xaxis').call(xaxis);
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'yaxis').call(yaxis);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: axes not on their proper place]

It is as if axes is completely unable to find SVG dimensions.

The only difference I see between my axes instantiation and those of tutorials is that they often create the SVG element on the fly. I would however prefer to manually place the SVG wherever I wish in the HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here.

Take a look at my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/e0xp6ae3/

-`scale(x).orient('bottom')` dictates the position of the axis ticks, and not the location of the axis itself. I fixed this by adding `.attr('transform','translate(0,'+280+')')` , where 280 is the desired y height of the axis.

-svg hides its overflow by default. 
In my first fiddle, i hacked together a solution with `position: relative` and `left:20px`. It's a horrible solution you see.

The D3 convention is to use margins, like this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563.

By creating the svg element on the fly, we can achieve cleaner, and more flexible code. Check out my updated fiddle that follows the D3 way.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/e0xp6ae3/1/

Basically, the space for the axes is given by the margins. The svg width and height play around the margins. Of course, you can still use hardcoded svg, you just need to change the code around to accommodate.

Comment: Thanks. Disclaimer: I am very new to javascript, I am just doing some educational applets as a hobby. The problem with creating the svg element on the fly is that you cannot place it where you want in the HTML, or can you?

Comment: Would you recommending using a `<div>` as a placeholder?

Comment: You definitely can. 'On the fly' elements, aka programmatically created elements, can be placed anywhere in HTML. For example if you wanted to put the svg in a div element that had a class "example", you would do `d3.select('div.example").append('svg')`. Querying the DOM is a core skill of web development. When i say "querying the DOM", i mean programmatically searching through the HTML for the elements you want.

Comment: Sounds good. I will use a placeholder then. Thanks! - The idea of a placeholder did not sound very elegant at first which was why I was reluctant, but it makes sense to separate the DOM and the graphics generation code because they really are independent: I could decide to replace the svg with a canvas in the future for example. This way everything is contained.

Comment: Actually, the `div` acts more like a container than a placeholder, giving also more flexibility for the stylesheet as well. Thanks again!